# show form and content in "verification" modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I would like to present a user with the form that they just filled out in a modal that pops up after they click "submit" for verification. I see this as a carbon copy of the form, but with each field disabled or grayed out so they can look it over and confirm that everything is right. To make changes to the form at this stage would require that they cancel out of the modal and would be taken back to their form.

I am having trouble getting the data that is contained within the form. Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

Or is there another strategy for allowing the user to look over what they just changed that I am missing/forgetting?

Comment: Show some HTML and any code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a clone version of the form in the modal:

```
var $clonedForm = $('#myformid').clone();
$('input, select, textarea', $clonedForm).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$clonedForm.appendTo('#modalid');
```

Comment: You are a champion. You just saved me a few hundred lines of code. Small typo, change $clonedFrom` to $clonedForm

Comment: Glad I could help. I fixed the typo